# object is not a function when using @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use `ng-bootstrap` with angular 6. I have done the following:

1) Added the import in `app.module.ts`

```
import {NgbPaginationModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

2) Added entry into imports

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NgbPaginationModule],
  ...
})
```

But I am getting the following error and the application is not loading:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ng-bootstrap.js:146
    at Object../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js (ng-bootstrap.js:148)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.config.ts:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../src/main.ts (environment.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:43)
```

Comment: Which version of ng-bootstrap are you using? See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started and pick the right version. or better, upgrade Angular to the latest stable version.

Comment: @JBNizet Version of ng-bootstrap was the problem, somehow I had missed the compatibility version of bootstrap with angular 6. Thanks a lot :)